# Elasticsearch: Date Aggregation Most Recent

Tags: date, search, elasticsearch, aggregation

I have query that works. It aggregates data based on Id and finds the **MOST RECENT** object based on the created field. The problem I have is that I would like to find the **SECOND MOST RECENT** instead of MOST RECENT. How would I go about this? I have been looking all through the docs and all I can find is range which doesn't help me to much. Thank you :)

```
{
    "query":{
      "match": {
         "name": "Robert"
      }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "previous": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "Id",
                "order": {"timeCreated": "desc"}
            },
            "aggs": {
                "timeCreated": {
                    "max": {"field": "created"}
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by most recent documents?? Please elaborate

Comment: @Richa what I mean by most recent is for the "sold" field I would like the most recent from current date. What I have seen in the docs is a bounded range of time but I would like the most recent from the current time a person does a search.

Comment: @Richa let me know if you need any more clarification. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You want to get only one document which is MOST RECENT..Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes :) I would like to obtain the most recent and obtain it complete field it relates too

Comment: But then, will calculating avg have any sense as avg is calculated on multiple figures? Or you have multiple documents created at same time? Please specify the date format of you date field?\.

Comment: I know what you mean.. I will edit the question for my specific code for you too see a better example which will make more sense @Richa

Comment: @Richa I have edited the question. As you can see I found out how to find the most recent but after trying it out I now realized I need SECOND most recent. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Top_hits` is what you are looking for. Use this:

```
{
"query":{
  "match": {
     "name": "A"
  }
},
"aggs": {
    "previous": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "Id"

        },
         "aggs": {
            "latestRecords": {
              "top_hits": {
                "sort": {
                  "created": {
                    "order": "desc"
                  }
                },
                "size" :2
              }
            }
          }
       }
     }
   }
```

Comment: this works great but without aggregations it would grab just the second most recent Robert. I would like to find the second most recent Robert from each Id. How can I expand on your solution to fit the need to find the second most Recent Robert from each Id.

Comment: This works perfect! You are amazing and seriously just made my day :) I was even shocked that it returned the entire object rather then just the Key and Count. Is this due do the top_hits feature? Anyway, thank you soooo much!

Comment: Happy To help.. :)